# How to filter a PostgreSQL table by passing an array of strings in the function

Tags: java, postgresql

I want to pass an array like `[group1, group2, group3]` and then filter the Postgres table column `groups`.

Create or replace function funname(groups text[])
Select *
From tableName
Where groupscolumn @> groups

Also kindly write the function for the same, getting an error while defining `character varying []`.

Comment: It's best if you show what you've tried so far and what went wrong, what error you're getting. Also, please clarify your second paragraph: do you mean you need the plain sql query in addition to a function that throws an error when it gets the `character varying[]` type (instead of `text`?), or that you are getting an error when you try to define the function accepting or returning this data type. It'd be easier to work this out if you showed your samples and error messages.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear to me what you want, but maybe you are looking for the ANY operator?

```
select * 
from some_unknown_table
where group_column = any(array_parameter);
```

This requires that the data type of the `group_column` and the one of the parameter match. E.g. if `group_column` is `text` or `varchar` the parameter needs to be declare as `text[]`. If `group_column` is e.g. an `integer`, the parameter needs to be declared as `integer[]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `unnest` function to convert an array in 'table' output and then filter the value that you need, for example:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT unnest (ARRAY['group1','group2','group3']) AS arr
) AS sub WHERE arr ='group3'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use join for groups array and SELECT WHERE group IN groups for filter:

```
import psycopg2


def filter_groups(group_names):


try:
    # connect to BD
    connection = psycopg2.connect(
        host="host",
        user="user",
        password="pass",
        database="db_name"
    )
except Exception as _ex:
    print("[INFO] Connection error", _ex)
try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        placeholders = ','.join(['%s'] * len(group_names))
        rsql = f"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE groups IN ({placeholders})"
        cursor.execute(rsql, group_names)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
except Exception as _ex:
    print("[INFO] Error while working with PostgreSQL", _ex)

if connection:
    connection.close()
    print("[INFO] PostgreSQL connection closed.")
return rows
```

Comment: You can use the array as is - [psycopg can map it to a SQL array](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#lists-adaptation), so you can simply `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE groups=ANY(%s)",group_names)`. You need to correct your indentation as well. Note that this is a plain SQL question with **`java`** tag added for a reason unspecified by the OP and you're presenting **`python`** code.